# ¿Como cambiar el orden de las columnas de una tabla en SqlServer?

Tags: sql-server

quisiera saber si hay una forma de cambiar el orden de las columnas de una tabla sin tener que borrar y crear otra vez la tabla, seria como pasar de esto:

campo1, campo2, campo3

a esto:

campo3, campo2, campo1

Comment: Lamentablemente cualquier alternativa, más fácil o más compleja, implica recrear la tabla

Comment: Si la tabla no tiene datos hay veces que desde el manejador te deja hacerlo pero hay veces que no y como te mencionan hay que volver a hacerla}

Comment: ¿por qué necesitas cambiar el orden? :) Si haces las consultas explícitas (que suele ser una buena idea), eso no va a importar

Answer (score 0):

Seleccionas la tabla, clic derecho, y presionas donde dice design o diseñador, ahi abre el diseñador de la tabla, en el cual al señalar el indice del campo que quieres, lo arrastras a donde lo quieres poner, y listo.

Comment: La operación que comentas, borra la tabla y la crea de nuevo, cosa que el AP pide explícitamente en la pregunta que no se haga.

Answer (score 0):

Mediante al uso de Transact-SQL
No se admite el cambio del orden de columna mediante instrucciones Transact-SQL. La tabla se debe eliminar y volver a crear para cambiar el orden de las columnas.

En cambio, a traves del Management de SQL Server existe esa posibilidad recreando la tabla.

**Recomendaciones**
Procedimientos recomendados con el orden de las columnas de tabla:

Para cambiar el orden de las columnas que se muestran en un conjunto de resultados, un informe o una aplicación, use el orden de columna en una instrucción SELECT (Transact-SQL). Especifique siempre las columnas por nombre en las consultas y aplicaciones en el orden en que desea que aparezcan.
No use SELECT * en aplicaciones. Las columnas agregadas o eliminadas podrían provocar errores o comportamientos inesperados en las aplicaciones.
Agregue nuevas columnas al final de las tablas.

[Enlace a la documentación oficial de learn.microsoft.com: Cambiar el orden de las columnas de una tabla](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/sql/relational-databases/tables/change-column-order-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).